# Mock for context-manager fails with AttributeError: __exit__

Tags: python, mocking

I am trying to patch some context manager function using a Mock so I can test that the code does sensible things given good, bad, and garbage input. Here is the test code with the `with` statement in it. The patch is done in the correct place in my code.

```
@patch("__main__.opened_w_error")
def test_get_recipe_file(self, mo):
    mo.return_value = (Mock(), None)
    mo.__enter__ = Mock(return_value=None)
    mo.__exit__ = Mock(return_value=None)
    with mo(…) as (fd, err):  # AttributeError: __exit__ is raised here.
        print(fd)
        print(err)
```

However the `with mo(…) as (fd, err)` raises `AttributeError: __exit__`.

The [documentation for mocking magic methods](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/magicmock.html?highlight=__exit__) states the you should use it as

```
with mo as (fd, err):
    …
```

The latter piece of code is what I am trying to mock.
 but that is not how I use it in my code. For those really interested, I am trying to mock [example 6 `opened_w_error()` in PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) which deals with opening files and catching errors. Thus the code is:

```
with open_w_error(filename, 'r') as (fd, err):
    …
```

The latter is what I am trying to mock.

Answer (score 14):

Note that the object you pass to the *with* statement is the one that should have `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, with the return value from `__enter__` used for the `as` construct. In your case, you are calling `mo(...)`, which returns `(Mock(), None)`, and this is not a context manager. You should move this return value to the `__enter__` method.

```
@patch("__main__.opened_w_error")
def test_get_recipe_file(self, mo):
    mo.__enter__ = Mock(return_value=(Mock(), None))
    mo.__exit__ = Mock(return_value=None)
    with mo as (fd, err):
        print(fd)
        print(err)
```

**EDIT**: If you still want to call `mo`, then make its return value a context manager.

```
@patch("__main__.opened_w_error")
def test_get_recipe_file(self, m_opened_w_error):
    mo = Mock()
    mo.__enter__ = Mock(return_value=(Mock(), None))
    mo.__exit__ = Mock(return_value=None)
    m_opened_w_error.return_value = mo
    with m_opened_w_error(...) as (fd, err):
        print(fd)
        print(err)
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is when you're calling `mo(..)` the object it is returning(`tuple`) doesn't have `__enter__` and `__exit__` attributes on it.

To fix this assign `mo` to `mo`'s `return_value` so that the context manager attributes you're setting on it can still be found.

```
@patch("__main__.opened_w_error")
def test_get_recipe_file(self, mo):
    mo.return_value = mo
    mo.__enter__ = Mock(return_value=(Mock(), None))
    mo.__exit__ = Mock(return_value=None)
    with mo('file', 'r') as (fd, err): 
        print(fd)
        print(err)
        mo.assert_called_once_with('file', 'r')  # Should be True
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this:

```
with mock.patch('__main__.opened_w_error') as mo:
    mo.__enter__ = Mock(return_value=(Mock(), None))
    mo.__exit__ = Mock(return_value=None)
    # Your code goes here
```